# Perl : creating array of known size

Tags: arrays, perl, variables

I have to store data from request runned with Parallel::ForkManager.
But it comes not in order, I mean, I poll all ports of a switch, but some of them answer faster than others. So, I don't know how to save it, to display it later.

Can I do like that ?

```
my @array = ();
$array[10] = "i am a string corresponding to port 10"
$array[2] = "the one for the port 2"
...
print @array;
```

Or should I use a %hash with number of port as keys, but it seems not the best.
Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this:

```
my @array = ();
$array[10] = "i am a string corresponding to port 10"
$array[2] = "the one for the port 2"
print @array;
```

But if some ports do not respond you will have undef entries in the slots of the array that were not filled.  As you say, using a hash would be cleaner:

```
my %hash;
$hash{10} = "I am port 10";
$hash{2} = "I am port 2";

foreach my $key (keys %hash) {
   print "$key: $hash{$key}\n";
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In Perl you don't have to worry about the sizes of arrays.  They grow as needed:

```
my @array; # defines an empty array

$array[0] = 4; # array has one element
$array[9] = 20; # array has 10 elements now

print join "-", @array;

# prints: 4--------20 because the empty places are undef
```

If you have many ports and are worried about having too many empty entries, use a hash.  I can't see any reason not to do it.

Comment: It prints "4         20", but with more spaces as SE won't print a run of those.

Answer (score 5):

A hash is a good data-type to use for "[sparse arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_array)."  It seems like you're describing just that; a sparse array -- one where most of the elements would be undefined.  Perl would let you pre-size a standard array, but that's not what you need.  You seem to need a hash, where it wouldn't matter if you have `$array[2]`, and `$array[23]`, but none between, for example.  Using a native array, as soon as you create `$array[23]`, all unused elements below 23 would spring into existence with '`undef`' as their value.

With the hash, you would have `$item{2}`, and `$item{23}`.  You could get a list of which items are being held in the hash using the `keys()` function.